# how to fix wrong ram usage in system monitor with environment variables

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, environment-variables, system-monitor, .profile

when I add environment variables to a program's .desktop shortcut, the program appears to only use around 100-250 kb ram when its using 1-3 gb ram.

this problem appears in the applications tab in system monitor for kubuntu 22.04. the process tab seems fine

how do I fix this? I know I can export the variable in my .profile but I really don't want to do so as I don't know if it plays well with other programs.

this is the command run by .desktop file `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 firefox %u`

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question ... So you want to fix how system-monitor reports used memory which you think is less than the actual used memory by e.g. FireFox in your example and not to know how to pass multiple environment variables to a certain command ... Is that right?

Comment: yes
If I invoke firefox with the env variable, system monitor just shows 250 kb ram in applications tab, but if I normally invoke firefox, it shows correct ram